# return value type does not match the function type C++

Tags: c++11, pointers

I am having a problem with the error "return value type does not match the function type" for both functions test and test2 below.

I am aware I am trying to pass in my "current" pointer to something's value and this function takes a float argument.

However, for the function getTest I tried creating a float variable chkTest to compensate for that...

I am still receiving the same error.

```
if (type == '1') 
    { 
        float chkTest = current->test;
        return getTest(chkTest);
    }
    if (type == '2') { return getTest2(current->test2); }
```

My declarations for these functions in the header is:

```
auto getTest(float t);
auto getTest2(float t);
```

and my function definitions are below:

```
  auto TransactionType::getTest(float t)
{
    //Do Something...
};
auto TransactionType::getTest2(float t2)
{
    //Do Something...
};
```

If I comment out my function definitions, then this error goes away, so obviously my problems are in the function definitions (correct me if I am wrong)

Please suggest on a solution and an explanation!

Thanks.

Comment: Using `auto` as a return type could be the source of your problems here. Why not be more specific?

Comment: are the definitions for getTest and getTest2 after your code using them or are they in another source file?

Comment: This isn't valid C++11.

Comment: `auto getTest(float t);` is not allowed in C++11.  In C++03 it meant `int getTest(float t);`.  Are you actually using a C++11 compiler? It should give you an error.